# Python Threading - Managing thread termination and the main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, keyboardinterrupt

Before you read on, know that I'm new to Python and very new to threading so forgive me if I misunderstand how threads work or make a rookie error :P

Short description of my goal:

1. The main thread (a) does some things (e.g. prints "begin!")
2. Main thread spawns a new thread (b) that first prints "Thread B
   started" and then prints x+1 forever (1, 2, 3 ...)
3. Main thread prints "Woop!"
4. Then the end of the main thread is reached, it terminates itself and
   then switches to thread b making b the main thread
5. Program is now running thread b as the main thread so is just
   printing x+1 forever and a has been forgotten and is no longer
   relevant
6. Ctrl+C will terminate thread b and effectively, the whole program
   will be terminated because thread a doesn't exist anymore

Here's what I have so far (the basics):

```
import threading, time

def printCount():
    print "Thread B started"
    x = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        x = x + 1
        print x

## User Code ##
print "begin!"
threadB = threading.Thread(target=printCount)
threadB.start()
print "woop!"
```

The requirements are:

- I don't want to modify below the 'User Code' mark much at all. I
  certainly don't want to wrap it in a class, a function or it's own
  thread
- Pressing Ctrl+C at any point should terminate the entire    program
  with no threads left running (Using something like: `except

  KeyboardInterrupt: os._exit(1))` inside User Code is fine
- Thread a *may* continue to run instead of making thread b the main
  thread, but in this case, I don't want the code to handle Ctrl+C
  terminating the    entire program inside the User Code section

This example is not my actual goal, just a simplified version of the problem I'm having. I'm trying to make an IRC framework where the user can import it and use the API very simply without messying their own code with threads and interrupts and the like. This is why it's important for the user code to be as clean as possible.

The framework would allow the user to create an IRC bot which runs forever, listening to commands whilst allowing the user to add their own commands. The Github link is [here](https://github.com/Jazcash/Jazbot) if you're interested (It's very WIP atm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "switch" threads. So once you're done with your main thread, you have to wait for the other threads to terminate using the method `join`. But note this:

- Since the `join` method is not interruptible with `KeyboardInterrupt`, you need to specify a timeout and loop over to detect user interrupts.
- Since you can't force a thread to terminate, you have to implement a stop mecanism using [threading.Event](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) for instance
- You also need to use [threading.Lock](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects) to prevent concurrent access on shared resources, like `sys.stdout` (used when you print)

I gathered these aspects in a class called `ThreadHandler`, please have a look:

```
import threading, time

def printCount(lock, stop):
    with lock:
        print "Thread B started"
    x = 0
    while not stop.is_set():
        time.sleep(1)
        x = x + 1
        with lock:
            print x

class ThreadHandler():
    STEP = 0.2

    def __init__(self, target):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.stop = threading.Event()
        args = (self.lock, self.stop)
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=target, args=args)

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def join(self):
        while self.thread.is_alive():
            try:
                self.thread.join(self.STEP)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                self.stop.set()

## User Code ##
print "begin!"
handler = ThreadHandler(target=printCount)
handler.start()
with handler.lock:
    print "woop!"
handler.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a short note on another question yesterday having similar issues, this is a check you could implement in the subthread "b":

Instead of `while 1:` do the following:

```
def printCount():
    main = None
    for t in threading.enumerate():
        if t.name == 'MainThread':
            main = t
    print "Thread B started"
    x = 0
    while main and main.isAlive():
        time.sleep(1)
        x = x + 1
        print x
```

It would be a good idea to store `main` in the global scope for all threads to use isntead of having to look up the main thread each and every initation of the sub-thread.
But this would do the work in your example.

`main` will be the handle towards your main thread by iterating through all threads (`.enumerate()`) and then placing the thread called "MainThread" into `main` and then calling `main.isAlive()` to check if it's still running.
if `main` is `None` or `False` or if `.isAlive()` returns `False` it will indicate that the thread is either non-existant or dead, shutting down your subthread :)

Comment: I want the thread containing printCount to continue to run forever, but this is interesting!

Comment: @Jazcash Oh my bad, thought i read that you wanted the threads to NOT run forever :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't switch threads like that. It doesn't work like that.

However you could use signals with a global flag `ALIVE`:

```
import threading, time, signal

ALIVE = True

def handle_sigint(signum, frame):
    global ALIVE
    ALIVE = False

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_sigint)

def printCount():
    print "Thread B started"
    x = 0
    while ALIVE:  # <--- note the change
        time.sleep(1)
        x = x + 1
        print x

## User Code ##
print "begin!"
threadB = threading.Thread(target=printCount)
threadB.start()
print "woop!"

signal.pause()  # <--- wait for signals
```

Now it will gracefully quit after pressing CTRL+C.

Comment: This is nice but then you have signal.pause() in the user code.
Maybe I should have produced a better example. Is there a way to start a thread once the main thread has ended?

Comment: @Jazcash You can start a thread from any thread. However you need the main thread to handle signals like CTRL+C. If the main thread terminates then you won't catch that signal.